# AWS api lambda, Как передать параметры запроса в URL

Tags: api, rest, lambda, amazon-web-services

Пробую настроить Lamda. Функция работает.
Но мне нужно принять входящие параметры для ее вызова и работы с данными.
Я хочу получить следущее.
API gateway

```
http://example.com/sys?login=nix&psw=123&phones=090909&mes=one
login=nix
psw=123
phones=090909
mes=one
```

Получить значения этих данных переданых в запросе GET, и применить их для работы функции lambda.
Работать с этими данными.
Я пробывал многое но не как не могу получить желаемый результат.

Comment: [How do I configure my API Gateway REST API to pass query string parameters to a backend Lambda function or HTTP endpoint?](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/pass-api-gateway-rest-api-parameters/)

Comment: Да, но как мне прочитать эти данные в функции lambda.
Другими , передать полученные данные в lamda?

Comment: [Set up Lambda custom integrations in API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-custom-integrations.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Когда твоя лямбда будет вызвана API Gateway сервисом, она получает в первый параметр *handler* функции объект *event*.

Вот например если handler функция такая (Python):

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    pass
```

То в *event* будет отправлен такой структуры объект как описано здесь:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html

В твоём случае:

```
event['requestContext']['resourcePath']  # example.com/sys
event['queryStringParameters']           # login=nix&psw=123&phones=090909&mes=one
event['body']                            # POST body я полагаю:  
                                       login=nix
                                       psw=123
                                       phones=090909
                                       mes=one
```